# Is my guilt natural?

Tags: personal-practice, philosophy, lay-buddhism

I find this troubling. My poor relationship with my adult children causes me distress. Logic and the dharma would suggest that severing ties with them would be a positive for both sides. But I cannot get over the feelings for neglect and guilt. Plus I may be causing them some current discomfort. They neglect me because they don't understand me seeking the jewel so I try to respect that BUT how do I get past this guilt and sadness?

Comment: Hi. Are you saying your practise of Buddhism is causing your children to be alienated from you?

Comment: yes. That is the situation.

Comment: Maybe there isn't, and maybe there even can't be, enough information in this question for people to understand and advise on the situation you're describing. Maybe it's a topic to discuss in person, perhaps with a teacher, or with a counsellor (Buddhist or otherwise) who might mediate between you and your children (if your children could accept such mediation, for the sake of improving or continuing their relationship with you).

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question properly, however, from my personal experience, it's best to make no public announcments that you are a Buddhist. Peopld are often confused about Buddhism and associate many different things. Similarly, a lot of people are just not interested in spirituality and/or don't know it any better. Don't talk about your 'philosophy'. Embody it. Don't even talk about Buddhist doctrines because intellectually they might comprehend, but constant reflection & direct experience is missing. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddha-Dhamma & Western families are often a problematic combination. Even in Asia, some families object to their members pursing the Dhamma. Even when a person's life is transformed so much for the better by Buddhist practise, often family members struggle to attribute appreciation towards Buddhism due to their own prejudices, misunderstandings &/or lack of spiritual values.

Ways to overcome sadness & guilt in respect to his situation is:

1. Reflect on the correctness of the Buddhist path.
2. Properly attribute causes or 'blame' to the other rather than to yourself.
3. Keep being nice & hopefully they will change via appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice stories, Nyom Kauva Aatma, [The Healing of the Bull: A Story](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/karunaratna/bl140_en.html) and [Prisoners of Karma](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/karunaratna/bl125_en.html)

Comment: When adding links to answers, please make a short content-description in case the link goes missing.

Comment: They're not easy to summarise -- they're a summary of basic Buddhist doctrine, gradually explained in the form of a dialog between animals, e.g. one unhappy talking with another who's more enlightened (or knowledgeable). Anyway the titles are included there in the hyperlinks -- and they're both by "Suvimalee Karunaratna" if you want to Google them (e.g. if the above links go missing).